# Webscraping with Julia?

Tags: web-scraping, julia

We are having a difficult time to find a good (actually, any) web scraping library or modules  for the [Julia](http://julialang.org/) language.

What we need is to have some kind of facility to make it easier to parse or find html elements and strings. Maybe even some kind of crawling on demand.

Update:

I'm looking for something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) (both are for Python).

Comment: That's fine if you don't like or know the Julia language. Please just don't down-vote the question because of it.

Answer (score 6):

Something like that probably doesn't exist yet.  Julia is young that way.  Either write you own, based on other packages like [Requests.jl](https://github.com/loladiro/Requests.jl), or bind to the Pthyon stuff you mention with [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl)